# ASP .Net Entity Framework .tt Files Not Nesting Under .edmx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm running an ASP .NET (v4.5) Web Site Project under VS 2012 Update 2. When I create a new entity model (.edmx) under the App_Code folder, nested under the .edmx file is only the .Designer.cs and the .edmx.diagram files. The associated .tt files are not nested. I think this is why, when I save the model, the T4 templates are not automatically transformed, even though that option is specified in the model properties.

Any ideas how to get this working? I cannot use the DependentUpon XML tag in a project file, since Web Site Projects do not have project files.

Comment: Can you open a bug at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: Done. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1095

Comment: For those of us who do have as `.csproj` file to edit, here is a reference for using the `DependentUpon` tag: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/11/nested-files-with-dependentupon-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Open the .tt file and choose save. This runs the T4 template.

Answer (score 1):

Web Site does not support Nested Project Files, whereas Web Applications support it.I highly you suggest to use a Web Application.

The only way that I found in past is to Run Manually T4 (Right Click on a TT File) or use a pre build event to run T4.