# Add Project File to Existing ASP.NET Web Site in TFS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an existing ASP.NET Web Site (targeting v4.5) in VS 2012, which is in source control and is used by several other developers. It does not have a project file associated with it in source control (we are using TFS). I am wanting to create a project file for this website and place it in source control.

Could someone give me step-by-step instructions on how to do this, without disrupting the other developers and without losing all previous change history?

Answer (score 1):

Well you should convert your web site project to a web application project. It has quite a few steps, you can follow steps provided by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx).

Comment: To make it explicit: web site "projects" do not have project files. In order to get one, you'll have to convert your web site to a Web Application Project.

Comment: Ugh. Forgot about that. The reason I'm trying to have a project file is to try and get this question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270356/asp-net-entity-framework-tt-files-not-nesting-under-edmx I really don't want to convert my project to a Web Application because I have a lot of mixing of VB and C#. Any suggestions, one the problem in the link? Thanks.