# Entity Framework files are not nested under the EDMX file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t4, edmx

I know this is duplicated from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270356/asp-net-entity-framework-tt-files-not-nesting-under-edmx) but I also have an issue where the TT files are not nested under the edmx file. The solution from the duplicated question just puts the entity classes under the TT but not the TT under the edmx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or, just don't use EDMX. If you want your application to be able to stay up to date with Entity Framework and not be locked forever at EF6, it's really the only smart move anyways: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit you .csproj and make sure you have `"DependentUpon>Model.edmx</DependentUpon>"` under `<Content Include="Model.tt">`. if you don't find it, add DependentUpon tag and save your .csproj file.

```
<Content Include="Model.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <DependentUpon>Model.edmx</DependentUpon>
  <LastGenOutput>Model.cs</LastGenOutput>
</Content>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has caused me issues all afternoon. I even looked through the project file and saw those lines but didn't try editing them. Thank you.